# Spark scala dataframe selecting multiple columns throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: scala, select, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm trying to select multiple columns from a dataframe to insert into a table using the following methods,

```
var result = cassandraDf.select(columnNames.map(c => col(c)): _*)
```

and

```
var result = cassandraDf.select(columnNames.head, columnNames.tail: _*)
```

Both the methods throws me java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 25, I have 26 columns in the dataframe

Is there any limit in selecting the columns in a dataframe?

Thanks,
Ash

Comment: I'm using this syntax all the time without problem. What version of spark do you run? What is in `columnNames`? What does `cassandraDF.show()` return?

Comment: cassandraDF.show works good, but the result is not. I'm using 1.6 version of spark. I have a huge DF joining few tables and I need to pick few columns, which columnNames have.

Comment: columnNames have 26 columns as seq which I'm passing in the DF. But the error is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 25

Comment: give some exemple. With the info you give, your error is not reproducible. To answer your question: there is no limit (that I encountered) in selecting columns in a dataframe (I just made a test in my 1.6.2 spark-shell with 4000 columns to be sure)

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to confirm if there is any limit. If no limit then it should be something wrong with the logic. I'll close this.